# Find Mahalanobis distance between 2 image histograms

Tags: matlab, histogram, distance, mahalanobis

I would like to find the Mahalanobis distance between 2 histograms of 2 images in MATLAB. I tried using the function `mahal` but the output should be just one number as a measure of distance, while `mahal` gives the distance between each correlating points. How can I obtain one value as a measure?

Comment: The Mahalanobis distance is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) between a point and a distribution (or histogram). How do you define your distance between two histograms?

Comment: What I want to do is compare the histograms of 2 images using the Mahalanobis distance. Even if I get the distance between each correlating points, how should I interpret these results in that case? My aim is to determine whether the images are similar or completely different based on color.